# While Registering multiple Apis with Spring-cloud-gateway

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

2024-02-06 17:56:19.601  INFO 25276 --- [io-8761-exec-10] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Registered instance CLOUD-API-GATEWAY/AshUday:CLOUD-API-GATEWAY:8761 with status UP (replication=true)
2024-02-06 17:56:21.374  INFO 25276 --- [a-EvictionTimer] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Running the evict task with compensationTime 0ms
2024-02-06 17:56:22.159  INFO 25276 --- [nio-8761-exec-9] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Cancelled instance CLOUD-API-GATEWAY/AshUday:CLOUD-API-GATEWAY:8761 (replication=false)
2024-02-06 17:56:22.665  WARN 25276 --- [nio-8761-exec-6] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : DS: Registry: cancel failed because Lease is not registered for: CLOUD-API-GATEWAY/AshUday:CLOUD-API-GATEWAY:8761
2024-02-06 17:56:22.665  INFO 25276 --- [nio-8761-exec-6] c.n.eureka.resources.InstanceResource    : Not Found (Cancel): CLOUD-API-GATEWAY - AshUday:CLOUD-API-GATEWAY:8761
2024-02-06 17:56:22.666  WARN 25276 --- [et_localhost-18] c.n.eureka.cluster.ReplicationTask       : The replication of task CLOUD-API-GATEWAY/AshUday:CLOUD-API-GATEWAY:8761:Cancel@localhost failed with response code 404
2024-02-06 17:56:22.666  WARN 25276 --- [et_localhost-18] c.netflix.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNode  : CLOUD-API-GATEWAY/AshUday:CLOUD-API-GATEWAY:8761:Cancel@localhost: missing entry.
2024-02-06 17:57:21.374  INFO 25276 --- [a-EvictionTimer] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Running the evict task with compensationTime 0ms
2024-02-06 17:58:21.375  INFO 25276 --- [a-EvictionTimer] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Running the evict task with compensationTime 0ms
2024-02-06 17:59:21.375  INFO 25276 --- [a-EvictionTimer] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Running the evict task with compensationTime 0ms

I was registering a diff diff APIs with Spring Could GatWay but so many try it not fix yet please tells us any solution . below is my YAML....
server:
port: 2222
spring:
application:
name: CLOUD-API-GATEWAY
cloud:
gateway:
discovery.locator:
enabled: true
lowerCaseServiceId: true
routes:
- id: greet-api
uri: lb://GREET-API
predicates:
- path=/greet

```
  - id: welcome-api
    uri: lb://WELCOME-API
    predicates:
    - path=/welcome
```

eureka:
instance:
prefer-ip-address: true
client:
fetch-registry: true
register-with-eureka: true
service-url:
defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka